# HTML file is showing up as blank in Chrome

Tags: html

I'm just starting to learn HTML and am following the Harvard CS50 class on Youtube.

I typed out the code exactly as the instructor did and yet when it opens in browser (Chrome) it's blank, and at the top it says "hello.html" rather than "Hello!" as it's supposed to.

I'm using Visual Studio Code.
I would also like to note that I can't figure out how to open it from the terminal like the instructor did, so I downloaded the extension "open in browser", if that makes a difference.

Here's my code, and I included a photo of what the terminal and overall page looks like in VS Code.
If anybody can help me with opening it from terminal: [image: Screenshot of VisualStudio]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello!
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, world!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you save the file? 
In pic you post, ıt seems does not saved yet. 
Also make sure, opening right file.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're talking about, but you don't need an extension to open an HTML file. Your browser does that every day. You did it about six times on the way to ask this question. If you downloaded an extension that claims to do that, best case scenario it's a silly joke, worst case scenario it's using your computer as a cryptomining slave.

Comment: the code works fine in chrome. you need to install a server to your Visual Studio Code to make it easier to launch any project or page

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white dot next to the hello.HTML title in your VS code means that the page is not saved. Do ctrl + s to save your work. Then refresh the page in your browser.

Also to make sure you have the correct URL in chrome, go into files and find your hello.html file. Then double click on it. It should open in a browser.

Glad to help.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I thought it auto saved based on past stuff I've done on VS Code but I guess it doesn't

Comment: @TheDoctor10XD No worries. Please click the tick next to my answer. :).

Answer (score 0):

You are new learner so :

- Press `ctrl+S` to save the file
- Then click `Run` button on top bar , you will see some option
- Now select option `Start Debugging`
- You will see option to launch with browsers like `Chrome` , `Edge` and select desired browser .
- Your html file will run and it will show result according to your code

like :

- `<title>Hello!</title>` will show the tab title as **Hello!**
- Use `<body><p>Hello, world!</p></body>` instead of `<body>Hello, world!</body>` and first one will show the content of browser window as **Hello, world!**

Comment: what @Matthias what are you trying to say brother

Comment: Nvm I see the tutorial was getting them to do that anyway.

Comment: oh I forget that and just copied the user code